# Finding the length of a line segment and the area of a trapezium

Tags: geometry

In the picture below, $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{DC}$ are parallel, and $F$ and $E$ are, respectively, the midpoints of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{DC}$. Compute the value of $x$ and the area of the grey trapezium.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGUik.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Properties Mid-Segment of a Triangle](http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/gp10/midlinel.htm):
$$x=GE=\frac12 AB=5$$
$$DC=x+1=6$$
$$S_{ABCD}=\frac{AB+CD}{2}\cdot8=64$$
$$FG=\frac12(x+1)=3$$
$$S_{FGCD}=\frac{FG+CD}{2}\cdot4=\frac{3+6}{2}\cdot4=18$$

Comment: I don't think you can say that $GE = \frac{1}{2}AB$...

Comment: $GE $ is a mid-segment of a triangle $ABC$

Comment: @GabrielVivaldini: that follows from Thales' theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution. By Thales' theorem, $FG=\frac{1}{2}CD$ and $GE=\frac{1}{2}AB$. It follows that $x=\color{red}{5}$, hence the area of $ACD$ equals $\frac{6\cdot 8}{2}=24$. By similarity between $AFG$ and $ADC$, it follows that the area of $AFG$ is one fourth of the area of $ACD$, hence $[CDFG]=\frac{3}{4}[ACD]=\color{red}{18}$.